# If an upper bidiagonal matrix has a repeated singular value, it must have a zero on its diagonal or superdiagonal

Tags: matrices

I have a question that mentioned in the book "Matrix Computations" by Golub and van Loan. "Show that if $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is an upper bidiagonal matrix having a repeated singular 
value, then $B$ must have a zero on its diagonal or superdiagonal. "

I have proved this question is right for an upper bidiagonal matrix $B\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. But I can not prove it for general upper bidiagonal matrices $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 2):

The self-adjoint tridiagonal matrix
$$
A = B^*B = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & a_1 & 0 &&  & \ldots & 0 \\ a_1 & b_2 & a_2 & 0 && \ldots & 0\\ 0 & a_2& b_3 & a_3 & 0 & \ldots &0\\ &&\ldots &&\\ 0 &&\ldots &&& a_{n-1}& b_n \end{pmatrix}
$$
has simple spectrum unless $a_j=0$ for some $j$ (in which case it consists of two or more separate blocks). This follows from the fact that $e_1$ is a cyclic vector if $a_j\not= 0$, and this we can confirm by just repeatedly applying $A$ to $e_1$.

Since $a_j=B_{jj}B_{j,j+1}$, the claim follows.